# How to subtract two dfs based on row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Imagine you have the following two dfs:

```
    lines
        line amount#1   line amount#2
        0   18.20        0.82
        1   NaN         NaN
        2   40.00       259.00
        3   388.00       NaN
        4   17.41         NaN





btws

    btw-amount#1    btw-amount#2
    0   0.0          0.14
    1   NaN          NaN
    2   NaN          NaN
    3   NaN          NaN
    4   NaN          NaN
```

I want to subtract these two dfs such that there is a new df that is like the following:

```
line amount#1   line amount#2
0   18.20        0.68
1   NaN         NaN
2   40.00       259.00
3   388.00       NaN
4   17.41         NaN
```

I've tried:

```
lines.subtract(btws, axis =0)
```

However, everyting turns NaN.

Please help!

Comment: `lines.to_numpy()-btws` -> the keys (columns) doesnot match and hence returns nan. Pandas aligns on indexes.

Comment: What is the rule that tells you which columns in one dataframe should be subtracted from what columns of the other?

Comment: the index of # @KarlKnechtel

Comment: in the column name

Comment: @Max Try `np.subtract(lines, btws)` which also preserves the column names from `lines` after subtraction.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma thats actually better in this usecase :)

Comment: I'd suggest rethinking your naming. Have your DataFrames named `lines` and `btws`, but have the columns the same in each, i.e. `'amount#1'`, `'amount#2'`-- you don't need the prefix if the DataFrame variable stores that information. Then the subtractions will align with a simple `df1 - df2` and you'll have code that now enforces alignment, unlike all of the other solutions that require perfect alignment (or raise FutureWarnings that soon it will do that automatically)

Answer (score 0):

```
result = lines.to_numpy() - btws.to_numpy()
result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=lines.columns)
```

Comment: just `result = lines - btws.to_numpy()` would work.